# Alter Table for Multiple Databases (same table name)

Tags: sql-server, alter-table

Is there a good way to Alter a table (add a column) for multiple databases (think like 50 or so). Or is it pretty much manual for all of them?

the Tables are all the same and the column added will be the same as well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the technique I frequently use to do things like this with dynamic SQL. This also has applications beyond just "looping" across databases, too.

Now, you didn't say *which* 50 databases, so I just went with everything in the instance, as that's a pretty common thing to do:

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(MAX);

SELECT
    @sql = ISNULL(@sql, N'') +
        N'ALTER TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(d.name) + N'.[dbo].[MyTable] ADD C1 int;'
    FROM sys.databases d
    WHERE
        (d.database_id > 4) AND /* No system databases */
        (d.state = 0) AND /* Online only */
        (d.is_distributor = 0) AND /* Not a distribution database */
        (d.is_read_only = 0) AND /* We can write to it */
        /* TODO: filter me more? */;

BEGIN TRANSACTION;
    EXEC(@sql);
COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

You can replace the `sys.databases` part with a list of constants, or a query from a master database table, or whatever is appropriate for your scenario. There's also no error checking, so you may want to add that.

<sub>(Yes, I left the syntax error in the above code on purpose.)</sub>

Comment: This was a perfect way for me to generate a script to use during production deploy.

Answer (score 1):

The lazy way: Use sp_MSForEachDB.

The safer way: Use a cursor and dynamic SQL.

```
DECLARE @db sysname
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max)

--Modify this query to specify which databases you want.
DECLARE db CURSOR FOR
SELECT name FROM master.sys.databases

OPEN db
FETCH NEXT FROM db INTO @db

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @sql = 'ALTER TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(@db) + '.dbo.sometable ADD somecolumn varchar(50)'
    EXEC (@sql)
    FETCH NEXT FROM db INTO @db
END

CLOSE db
DEALLOCATE db
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Aaron's version of [**sp_MSforeachdb**](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2201/making-a-more-reliable-and-flexible-spmsforeachdb/) which is more reliable than the native one.

Example :

```
EXEC sp_foreachdb
       @command = N'ALTER TABLE table_name ADD C1 int;',
       @user_only = 1 -- only user databases
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a script to add a column for a table.  If all of the tables are identical it is not too hard.

1. Create the ALTER TABLE script.
2. Run that script in every database where the table exists.

That is all there is to it.  You can, of course, automate the distribution across several dataases on a server or even several servers.  Depending on your landscape the details are different.  Assuming that all databases are on a single server it could be:

Companies like Red Gate, Apex, etc have tools to help you automate this if you choose to acquire a tool.