# Create DDL Trigger Dynamically

Tags: sql-server, dynamic-sql, ddl-trigger

I'm trying to create a DDL Trigger dynamically so I can create a job that checks each database and creates the trigger if it's not already in place. To do this, I'm using sp_foreachdb. The code works on it's on but I can't get it to work with sp_foreachdb so I'm guessing I've missed a single quote. However, I'm struggling to find the error. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_foreachdb
'
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.triggers T WHERE T.name = 
''Database_DDL_Audit'') AND ''?'' <> ''TempDB''
BEGIN   
EXEC
(
''
CREATE TRIGGER Database_DDL_Audit ON DATABASE   
FOR DDL_DATABASE_LEVEL_EVENTS
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @EventDataXml   XML
DECLARE @SchemaName     SYSNAME
DECLARE @ObjectName     SYSNAME
DECLARE @EventType      SYSNAME 

SET @EventDataXml = EVENTDATA()

SELECT  
@EventType  = @EventDataXml.value(''''(/EVENT_INSTANCE/EventType)[1]'''', ''''SYSNAME'''')
, @SchemaName = @EventDataXml.value(''''(/EVENT_INSTANCE/SchemaName)[1]'''', ''''SYSNAME'''')
, @ObjectName = @EventDataXml.value(''''(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectName)[1]'''', ''''SYSNAME'''') 

INSERT [ServerAdmin].[dbo].[ServerChangeLog] 
(
[CreateDate]
, [LoginName]
, [ComputerName]
, [ProgramName]
, [DBName]
, [SQLEvent]
, [SchemaName]
, [ObjectName]
, [SQLCmd]
, [XmlEvent]
)
SELECT  GETDATE()
        , SUSER_NAME()
        , HOST_NAME()
        , PROGRAM_NAME()
        , @EventDataXml.value(''''(/EVENT_INSTANCE/DatabaseName)[1]'''', ''''SYSNAME'''')
        , @EventType
        , @SchemaName
        , @ObjectName
        , @EventDataXml.value(''''(/EVENT_INSTANCE/TSQLCommand)[1]'''', ''''NVARCHAR(MAX)'''')
        , @EventDataXml
''
)
END
'
```

The error I'm getting is

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure Database_DDL_Audit, Line 40 [Batch Start Line 0]
>   Incorrect syntax near '@EventDataXml'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing an `END`. See updated as below:

Note: Use [Aaron's version](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/50001) of `sp_msforeachdb`

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max) 

set @sql = '
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.triggers T WHERE T.name = 
''Database_DDL_Audit'') AND ''?'' <> ''TempDB''
BEGIN   
EXEC
(
''
CREATE TRIGGER Database_DDL_Audit ON DATABASE   
FOR DDL_DATABASE_LEVEL_EVENTS
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @EventDataXml   XML
DECLARE @SchemaName     SYSNAME
DECLARE @ObjectName     SYSNAME
DECLARE @EventType      SYSNAME 

SET @EventDataXml = EVENTDATA()

SELECT  
@EventType  = @EventDataXml.value(''''(/EVENT_INSTANCE/EventType)[1]'''', ''''SYSNAME'''')
, @SchemaName = @EventDataXml.value(''''(/EVENT_INSTANCE/SchemaName)[1]'''', ''''SYSNAME'''')
, @ObjectName = @EventDataXml.value(''''(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectName)[1]'''', ''''SYSNAME'''') 

INSERT [ServerAdmin].[dbo].[ServerChangeLog] 
(
[CreateDate]
, [LoginName]
, [ComputerName]
, [ProgramName]
, [DBName]
, [SQLEvent]
, [SchemaName]
, [ObjectName]
, [SQLCmd]
, [XmlEvent]
)
SELECT  GETDATE()
        , SUSER_NAME()
        , HOST_NAME()
        , PROGRAM_NAME()
        , @EventDataXml.value(''''(/EVENT_INSTANCE/DatabaseName)[1]'''', ''''SYSNAME'''')
        , @EventType
        , @SchemaName
        , @ObjectName
        , @EventDataXml.value(''''(/EVENT_INSTANCE/TSQLCommand)[1]'''', ''''NVARCHAR(MAX)'''')
        , @EventDataXml
END
''
)
END
'
print @sql
```